# How to calculate the size of dataframe in bytes in Spark 3.2 version?

Tags: apache-spark

I am currently using spark 3.2 and `spark.sessionState.executePlan` method which I am trying to use is expecting two args - `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan`, `scala.Enumeration.Value`.

what is the value for second argument (scala.Enumeration.Value)?

I am using this to get the dataframe size:

```
BigInt dfSize = getSparkSession().sessionState().executePlan(logicalPlan).optimizedPlan().stats().sizeInBytes();
```

Build error:

```
method executePlan in class org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan,scala.Enumeration.Value
[ERROR]   found: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan
[ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at version 3.2.0's [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SessionState.scala#L122-L126) of the `executePlan` method:

```scala
def executePlan(
    plan: LogicalPlan,
    mode: CommandExecutionMode.Value = CommandExecutionMode.ALL): QueryExecution =
  createQueryExecution(plan, mode)
```

You see that the second argument is of type `CommandExecutionMode.Value`. Now, this is actually a simple `scala.Enumeration` object. [It looks like this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5d45a415f3a29898d92380380cfd82bfc7f579ea/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/QueryExecution.scala#L389-L400):

```scala
/**
 * SPARK-35378: Commands should be executed eagerly so that something like `sql("INSERT ...")`
 * can trigger the table insertion immediately without a `.collect()`. To avoid end-less recursion
 * we should use `NON_ROOT` when recursively executing commands. Note that we can't execute
 * a query plan with leaf command nodes, because many commands return `GenericInternalRow`
 * and can't be put in a query plan directly, otherwise the query engine may cast
 * `GenericInternalRow` to `UnsafeRow` and fail. When running EXPLAIN, or commands inside other
 * command, we should use `SKIP` to not eagerly trigger the command execution.
 */
object CommandExecutionMode extends Enumeration {
  val SKIP, NON_ROOT, ALL = Value
}
```

#### Conclusion

So, to answer your question, you can `import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CommandExecutionMode` and use either value of the following (in function of which one you want to use, see the comments in the code in the code block above):

- `CommandExecutionMode.SKIP`
- `CommandExecutionMode.NON_ROOT`
- `CommandExecutionMode.ALL`

#### BUT

You see in the function signature of `executePlan` that the second argument, `logicalPlan` has a default value and is hence optional. So I would not expect `executePlan` to fail if you only supply the logicalPlan. In fact, the following code executes without issues in a spark-shell:

```scala
scala> val logicalPlan = Seq(1,2,3).toDF.queryExecution.logical

scala> spark.sessionState.executePlan(logicalPlan)

res0: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution =
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [value#1]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
value: int
LocalRelation [value#1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [value#1]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [value#1]
```